How do I get two different menus to show based on users role
I am creating a navigation menu, and what I am trying to do is if the user is not an admin, then show one menu, and if they are an admin, show a different menu. I have tried several other ways to do this but with no success.
If(!IsBlank(MicrosoftEntraID.CheckMemberGroupsV2(User().Email, ["xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"]).value), Set(varIsAdmin, false), Set(varIsAdmin, true));
    
    If(IsBlank(varIsAdmin),
            colSidebarMenu( 
                Table(
                    {Value: "Home", Icon: Icon.Home, Screen: Home},
                    {Value: "Add/Edit Pubs", Icon: Icon.Tablet, Screen: EditPubs},
                    {Value: "Create/Edit Rept", Icon: Icon.DocumentWithContent, Screen: Reports},
                    {Value: "Report Status", Icon: Icon.ListWatchlistRemind, Screen: ReportStatus},
                    {Value: "Search Abstract", Icon: Icon.Search, Screen: Search},
                    {Value: "Late PI Proj. Rpts", Icon: Icon.LevelsLayersItems, Screen: LatePI},
                    {Value: "Create/Edit Abst.", Icon: Icon.Document, Screen: Abstract},
                    {Value: "My Profile", Icon: Icon.Person, Screen: Profile}
                )
                ),
                colSidebarMenu(
                Table(
                    {Value: "Home", Icon: Icon.Home, Screen: Home},
                    {Value: "Add/Edit Pubs", Icon: Icon.Tablet, Screen: EditPubs},
                    {Value: "Create/Edit Rept", Icon: Icon.DocumentWithContent, Screen: Reports},
                    {Value: "Report Status", Icon: Icon.ListWatchlistRemind, Screen: ReportStatus},
                    {Value: "Search Abstract", Icon: Icon.Search, Screen: Search},
                    {Value: "Late PI Proj. Rpts", Icon: Icon.LevelsLayersItems, Screen: LatePI},
                    {Value: "Create/Edit Abst.", Icon: Icon.Document, Screen: Abstract},
                    {Value: "My Profile", Icon: Icon.Person, Screen: Profile},
                    {Value: "Admin", Icon: Icon.Lock, Screen: Admin}
                    )
                )
    
    );


Your code looks good, but you can make it more readable by doing the following:
    
If(!IsBlank(MicrosoftEntraID.CheckMemberGroupsV2(User().Email, 
    ["xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"]).value), 
    Set(varIsAdmin, false), Set(varIsAdmin, true)
);

colSidebarMenu( 
    Table(
        {Value: "Home", Icon: Icon.Home, Screen: Home},
        {Value: "Add/Edit Pubs", Icon: Icon.Tablet, Screen: EditPubs},
        {Value: "Create/Edit Rept", Icon: Icon.DocumentWithContent, Screen: Reports},
        {Value: "Report Status", Icon: Icon.ListWatchlistRemind, Screen: ReportStatus},
        {Value: "Search Abstract", Icon: Icon.Search, Screen: Search},
        {Value: "Late PI Proj. Rpts", Icon: Icon.LevelsLayersItems, Screen: LatePI},
        {Value: "Create/Edit Abst.", Icon: Icon.Document, Screen: Abstract},
        {Value: "My Profile", Icon: Icon.Person, Screen: Profile}
    )
);

If(varIsAdmin,
    Patch(colSidebarMenu, Defaults(), 
    {Value: "Admin", Icon: Icon.Lock, Screen: Admin}
   )
);

This will create your table with default options, and if the current user is admin, one more value will be patched if Admin.

So I managed to fix it like this, but your example pointed me to the right direction.
If(!IsEmpty(MicrosoftEntraID.CheckMemberGroupsV2(User().Email, 
["18fbed88-0ff6-4d6a-9b29-6f93ac6d4683"]).value), 
Set(varIsAdmin, false), Set(varIsAdmin, true)

);
If(varIsAdmin,
ClearCollect(colSidebarMenu,
    Table(
    {Value: "Home", Icon: Icon.Home, Screen: Home},
    {Value: "Add/Edit Pubs", Icon: Icon.Tablet, Screen: EditPubs},
    {Value: "Create/Edit Rept", Icon: Icon.DocumentWithContent, Screen: Reports},
    {Value: "Report Status", Icon: Icon.ListWatchlistRemind, Screen: ReportStatus},
    {Value: "Search Abstract", Icon: Icon.Search, Screen: Search},
    {Value: "Late PI Proj. Rpts", Icon: Icon.LevelsLayersItems, Screen: LatePI},
    {Value: "Create/Edit Abst.", Icon: Icon.Document, Screen: Abstract},
    {Value: "My Profile", Icon: Icon.Person, Screen: Profile},
    {Value: "Admin", Icon: Icon.Lock, Screen: Admin}
)
),
ClearCollect(colSidebarMenu,
    Table(
    {Value: "Home", Icon: Icon.Home, Screen: Home},
    {Value: "Add/Edit Pubs", Icon: Icon.Tablet, Screen: EditPubs},
    {Value: "Create/Edit Rept", Icon: Icon.DocumentWithContent, Screen: Reports},
    {Value: "Report Status", Icon: Icon.ListWatchlistRemind, Screen: ReportStatus},
    {Value: "Search Abstract", Icon: Icon.Search, Screen: Search},
    {Value: "Late PI Proj. Rpts", Icon: Icon.LevelsLayersItems, Screen: LatePI},
    {Value: "Create/Edit Abst.", Icon: Icon.Document, Screen: Abstract},
    {Value: "My Profile", Icon: Icon.Person, Screen: Profile}
    )
)

);
I also had to change IsBlank to IsEmpty(because I am working with text).
